# Why "he is known to me" instead of "he is known by me"

Tags: grammar, passive-voice

Why do we say *he is known to me* instead of *he is known by me*? We know that the passive is formed by *by*. Then why is it not *he is known by me*? Actually I want to know the structure.

Answer (score 3):

It's not the passive form, *known* here is an adjective.

Comment: Yes, as with "he is familiar to me", "he is unknown to me", "he seems familiar to me" ... (Though 'He is known by all and sundry' _is_ a passive; cf *'He is unknown by all and sundry', where the asterisk signifies 'grammatical only amongst wags')

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I didn’t realise we had typographical marks to indicate grammaticality limited to sports players’ significant others. How advanced!

Comment: They're usually known as 'superstars'.

Comment: what is superstars

Comment: @zaforahmed: _Superstar_ is an American term referring to a performer (usually a singer, but also actors and musicians) who is very famous and considered to be one of the best performers. It's a term of respect, and a common ambition. To be called a superstar (by someone you respect) is a compliment.

Comment: I can see that known is an adjective, but I can't see the rationale for why it is "known to" and not "known by".   In either case we are describing (adjective) him as "known", and qualifying the "kind" of known that we are talking about.   This might be clarified by answering the second part of the question: what, grammatically, is this complex adjectival structure?   (hopefully the answer to that explains "to" instead of "by")

Answer (score 2):

**Both forms are correct and used. They mean slightly different things.**

"He is known to me" means "I am aware of him". It implies only a level of knowing that is casual.

"He is known by me" is unusual but can be sometimes used. It implies a deeper level of knowledge than "He is known to me".

Comment: I'd use "known to him" with people but "known by him" with facts. It's definitely different types of knowledge but I'm not quite sure what the difference is.

Answer (score -2):

I think because "knowing him" is not an action done to him, so he is not and can't be "known by you".