# Passive form of "Who knows you?" is it "to whom are you known?" or "by whom are you known?"

Tags: grammar

What is the passive form of "Who knows you?", is it "to whom are you known?" or "by whom are you known?"?

Some people are saying 'to', some are saying 'by'. I'm confused.

If it is one, then why not other?

Comment: Is being known by Tom the same as being known to Tom?  If not, use the one appropriate for your meaning.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why "he is known to me" instead of "he is known by me"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/174241/why-he-is-known-to-me-instead-of-he-is-known-by-me) The passive uses 'by'; the use of 'to' uses 'known' as an adjective rather than a verb form (or perhaps 'known to' as a unary idiom, a lexeme). Compare 'He seems familiar to me'. // 'Known to' does not mean quite the same as 'known by'; there is a greater hint of a reasonable depth of relationship / understanding, rather than a mere nodding acquaintance, with the latter.